# Error when adding powerShell snapins for Microsoft SharePoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-5.0

I have SharePoint PowerShell scripts that I need to run locally on PowerShell v5.0

I've tried to execute `Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"` but it throws error:

> The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer.

How do I download those dlls and install the snap-in?

Comment: You need to provide a little more information on this. Have you tried to download or install the PowerShell SnapIns yet? If so, what happens? Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: I din't find exact files to download and install the snap-in "microsoft.sharepoint.powershell".
I'm using SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to either RDP onto the SharePoint Server itself, or use a PSSession to connect to the Server via PowerShell like this:

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName SP2013Server
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
```

To do this [PSRemoting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting) will need to be enabled on the Server

Comment: Thank you:) im able to get all sharepoint-powershell cmdlets now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the case, but I've got this error message when, for mistake, I ran scripts on powershell ISE(x86) instead of the 64 bit version.